# "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" when i am trying to login with gmail

Tags: php, google-oauth, gmail-api, x-cart

**this is my get access token method**
protected function getAccessToken($code)
{
$request = new \XLite\Core\HTTP\Request(static::TOKEN_REQUEST_URL);

```
$request->body = array(
    'code'          => $code,
    'client_id'     => $this->getClientId(),
    'client_secret' => $this->getClientSecret(),
    'redirect_uri'  => $this->getRedirectUrl(),
    'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
);


$response = $request->sendRequest();

$accessToken = null;
if (200 == $response->code) {
    $data = json_decode($response->body, true);
    $accessToken = $data['access_token'];
}

return $accessToken;
```

}

**and here i got the response in my logs:**

```
[06:35:13.000000] array (
  'request response from google' => 
  (object) array(
     '__CLASS__' => 'PEAR2\\HTTP\\Request\\Response',
     'code' => 400,
     'headers' => 
    (object) array(
       '__CLASS__' => 'PEAR2\\HTTP\\Request\\Headers',
       'iterationStyle' => 'lowerCase',
       'fields:protected' => 'Array(13)',
       'camelCase:protected' => NULL,
       'lowerCase:protected' => NULL,
    ),
     'cookies' => 
    array (
    ),
     'body' => '{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}',
     'scheme' => 'https',
     'host' => 'accounts.google.com',
     'path' => '/o/oauth2/token',
     'uri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
     'port' => 443,
  ),
)
```

you can see the in response body if you required any thing else let me know

Comment: $request->body = array(
            'code'          => $code,
            'client_id'     => $this->getClientId(),
            'client_secret' => $this->getClientSecret(),
            'redirect_uri'  => $this->getRedirectUrl(),
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
        );

Comment: my request is like this

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] as well as any error messages.   Images are not helpful we need the code

Comment: you can see the edited question now.the above live is with the code . i have a method with the name of getAccessToken($code). in this method i am sending the request

Comment: are you sure the $code is valid? how long did you wait to use it.

Comment: my code =  4/0AX4XFWGS91NTNBDPQHJL9DEERKXWXNZLB5VBZEFNZVUBQFGNQ4QYOVIBXLRRNLRFEFXHAW

Comment: while when i am sending it to the request of body the whole data is like this=

Comment: the code expires in under five minutes and can only be used once.

Comment: 'request body' => 'code=4%2F0AX4XFWGS91NTNBDPQHJL9DEERKXWXNZLB5VBZEFNZVUBQFGNQ4QYOVIBXLRRNLRFEFXHAW&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevstr.s8r.me%2F%3Ftarget%3Dsocial_login%26action%3Dlogin%26auth_provider%3Dgoogle&grant_type=authorization_code',

Comment: so request is converting code this '/' to '%' is this the issue you can see the above request data

Comment: If you have solved your issue make sure to post your own answer so that you will help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

The post body is sent as a query string not an array

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=AuthorizationCode&client_id=ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=RedirectURI&grant_type=authorization_code
```

remember the code will expire in five minutes and can only be used once.

I beleave in php you should be using [http-build-query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for your post data.

Comment: actualy i am using x cart(e commerce platfrom) they provide the module for social login . i need to fix my request could you please help me using my request

Comment: Note this is not social login this is Oauth2.